# How can I stitch two 1920x2160 TIFF files, side by side

Tags: merge, tiff

Right now I have two sets of 1920 x 2160 sequential TIFF files about 20,000 files each.
And I want to stitch these sequential files to make a 3840 x 2160 TIFF file from these.

Is there any way using a free solution to do this.
I tried to use strip of images function on XnView, however it seems not to work stitching sequential files.

Comment: Give this a go http://www.coolutils.com/Online/TIFF-Combine/

Comment: I'm sorry but your question doesn't make sense... I find it unclear what kind of sets of files you have. `ImageMagick` is free software and can do a lot of tricks though, probably also what you want.

Comment: The files are resolution 1920x2160 sequential TIFF files. In left side and right side folder, 20,000 files each. I will try using ImageMagick.